# Object creating and invoking using method reference

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

I wanted to understand `::` operator a bit more, and with this intention, created a sample program:

```
public class Second {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        doWork(new int[] { 1, -1, 2, -1, 0, 2, 0, 0 });

    }

    public static void doWork(int[] nums) {

        // This is a compilation error - how do
        // we create an object and invoke method?
        Arrays.stream(nums).forEach((Myclass1::new)::print);  
    }


    @FunctionalInterface
    interface MyInterf1 {
        public abstract void print(int i);
    }

    public class Myclass1 implements MyInterf1 {

        private int i;

        public Myclass1(int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void print(int i) {
            System.out.println(this.i);
        }
    }
   }
```

My intent is simple:

To print each element, using "::" to invoke the print() method of `Myclass1`.  As this method is non-static, so I need to first create the object of this class and then invoke.

Is it possible at all? How do we simplify both object creation (using::) and then invoking method on that object?

Answer (score 2):

Your `print` method doesn't need the `i` argument, since it ignores it and prints the instance variable `this.i`.

And I'd change `Myclass1` to be a `static` class, so that you don't have to worry about an enclosing instance of `Second` class.

Now you can write:

```
class Second {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        doWork(new int[] { 1, -1, 2, -1, 0, 2, 0, 0 });

    }

    public static void doWork(int[] nums) {

        Arrays.stream(nums).mapToObj(Myclass1::new).forEach (Myclass1::print);

    }


    @FunctionalInterface
    interface MyInterf1 {
        public abstract void print();
    }

    public static class Myclass1 implements MyInterf1 {

        private int i;

        public Myclass1(int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(this.i);
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

First, `Arrays.stream(nums)` creates an `IntStream`.

Then, `mapToObj(Myclass1::new)` transforms each `int` to a `Myclass1` instance by passing the `int` to the `Myclass1(int i)` constructor. This results in a `Stream<Myclass1>`.

Finally, `forEach(Myclass1::print)` prints the `int` values by calling the `print()` method of each `Myclass1` instance.